# "version" lock value for populating tables

Tags: grails, version, grails-orm

I need to populate a couple of tables from a db that was created when the grails app was run. I kept the "version" column for hibernate's locking strategy, so I need to know what value is safe to put in that field when importing the data to those tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value that Hibernate uses is 0 but any value is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be modifying existing records while your application is running be sure to increment the value of 'version'.